# How to prove a Big-O bound

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics

In "Numerical Analysis: Mathematics of Scientific Computing" (3rd ed), chapter 1.2, the author says  that $sin x = х - \frac{x^3}{6} + \mathcal{O}(х^5) \quad (х \rightarrow 0)$. This means that on a neighborhood of $0$, there exists a constant $C$ such that $\left|sin x - х + \frac{x^3}{6}\right| \leq C\left|х^5\right|$ and that it can be verified by using Taylor's theorem up to $n=4$.

Doing that, I got to $\frac{\left|x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} +R_4(x)- x+ \frac{x^3}{6}\right|}{\left|х^5\right|} =\left|\frac{1}{5!} - \frac{x^2}{7!} + \frac{x^4}{9!} \right| + \frac{\left|R_4(x)\right|}{\left|х^5\right|}$

And I got stuck there. I know that since I'm in a neighborhood of $0$, $\frac{x^2}{7!} + \frac{x^4}{9!}$ go to $0$, and $\frac{1}{5!}$ is just a constant, but I don't know what to do with the $\frac{\left|R_4(x)\right|}{\left|х^5\right|}$ factor.

How can I prove that it is bounded? how can I find the $C$ that I need?

And to that effect, the first problem of that section is to find for the smallest integer $k$ such that $arctan(x) = x+ \mathcal{O}(х^k)$ as $(х \rightarrow 0)$

I suppose that I need to do something similar, that is, to calculate $\frac{\left|x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} + \frac{x^9}{9}- ... +R_n(x)- x\right|}{\left|х^k\right|}$. I assume that I should use $n = 3$, but I don't know how to prove that.

Am I on the right path?

Comment: What is $E_4$? You should be using a form of Taylor's theorem with remainder that describes the remainder in terms of derivatives, e.g: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's supposed to be the error function. I will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you overcomplicated it for yourself and they meant $n=4$ to include the $0$ terms.

We know by Taylor's theorem that there exists an $R(x)$ such that
$$
\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+R_5(x)x^5
$$
with $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} R_5(x)=0$.

By definition of the limit, if we choose $\varepsilon=1$, there must exist $\delta$ such that if $|x|<\delta$ then $|R(x)| < \varepsilon=1$.

Bringing this together, we can choose $C=1$ and say that for all values of $x$ with $|x|<\delta$, we know that
$$
|R(x)x^5|<C|x^5|
$$
which proves our claim that
$$
\sin(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(x^5)
$$

Comment: The limit of $R_5$ has to exist, but not necessarily as zero. Which would be difficult for its value $1/5!$

Comment: I was just using the first Peano form of Taylor's Theorem as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).

Comment: For that you need the last term of the partial sum of the same degree. That is, $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+o(x^5).$$

Answer (score 1):

The power series of the sine is an alternating series. If the size of the terms is monotonically falling, then the partial sums are alternatingly upper and lower bounds of the limit. This is one corollary to the Leibniz test.

The series remainder to $\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}6$ is
$$
\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}\pm...+(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+...
$$
Its terms are falling if $x^2<6\cdot 7$. Starting with the lowest partial series, the remainder value lies between $0$ and $\frac{x^5}{120}$. So $$C=\frac1{120}$$ is one possibility.